# Can you change the menus in GIMP via a theme?

Tags: themes, gimp

I want to change the content of the GIMP menus to make it a simpler application and hide all the advanced stuff that I never use.

Is it possible to do this via a theme or does it require creating a custom build from source?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to edit the menu definition XML files in `/usr/share/gimp/2.0/menus/`.

The key file for the application menu is `image-menu.xml`.

You will not be able to get everything this way - for example, menu entries created by plug-ins will still show up. But if you do not want a plug-in to show up there, you probably do not want it in your GIMP at all, either.

Please note: changes in these menu definition files affect all users of your system.

Comment: BTW... to anyone who does changes like this: make it obvious (wake-you-in-the-middle-of-the-night-and-you'll-know-it obvious) to yourself and any other user that you have done this change. Do not waste anyone's time by asking why a menu entry isn't there, only for your own change to be revealed after hours of research.